# Question about the formula of glPolygonOffset

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL spec 4.5, section 14.6.5, the formula used to calculate the depth offset is

```
o = m * factor + r * units.
```

where `m` is the magnitude of the gradient.

Why is the magnitude of gradient used instead of `fwidth`, i.e. `|dFdx|+|dFdy|`? As I understand it, to find the maximum offset within a pixel, say `[0,1]x[0,1]`, we can find the maximum value of the following function,

```
f(x,y)=|dFdx*(x-0.5)+dFdy*(y-0.5)|
```

With some calculus, we can find out that the maximum value is `0.5(|dFdx|+|dFdy|)`.

Perhaps my understanding is wrong, could anyone help explain it?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I understand the effect of `glPolygonOffset`, what I'm not clear about is the reason why the magnitude of the gradient is used as the factor. Wouldn't it be more correct to use `fwidth` as the factor?

Comment: Is `basic machine unit` you're referring to the precision of the depth buffer?

Comment: It seems my question is a bit unclear, I've tried to rephrase it, I don't know if I've made it clear now, thanks.

Comment: I can't tell you what people where thinking back then, I can only guess that they refered back to well-established mathamatical properties, and the magnitude of the gradient represents the maximum rate of change across all possible directions. However, since we usually think about the area of a pixel, and the distance to the pixel boarder will actually vary with the direction of the maximum rate of change, we would have to scale it by some varying value depending on that direction to get the exact maximum over the pixel, and an `fwidth` approach would indeed allow to directly calculate that

Comment: However, those observations are quite moot in practice, since GPUs are allowed to approximate this with just taking the maximum of the slop in x and y direction, so if you want to get some depth offset to be high enogh to peresent the offsets within the whole pixel area, you have to take this approximation into account and will have to over-shoot with `factor` to make sure it is still enough for the worst case of `dFdx == dFdy`.

Comment: Any, you will see that interestingly, `0.5 * (|dFdx | + |dFdy|) <= max(|dFdx|, |dFdy|) <= sqrt( |dFdx|^2 + |dFdy|^2)`, so the allowed approximation is basically just set up in a way that it always fullfills at least the minimum value you came up with.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.